# jquery toggleclass to all elements except links

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I use jQuery toggleClass like this:

```
$('.demo').toggleClass('classa classb');
```

Now how can I toggle this to all elements that have class `demo` except for links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the not selector:

```
$( ".demo" ).not( "a" ).toggleClass( "classa classb" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$('.demo:not(a)').toggleClass('classa classb');
```